# Can someone please tell me what this notation means: $D^1(\mathfrak{gl}(V)) = \mathfrak{sl}(V)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is in the context of algebras.  This is not in the text provided by the instructor, nor is it in my notes, but I am asked to prove this in a homework problem.  Can somebody please explain to me what this means?

Comment: $D^1(\mathfrak g)$ is the set of commutator $[x,y] \in \mathfrak g$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(L, [\cdot, \cdot])$ is a Lie algebra, then the *derived Lie algebra* of $L$ is $L' = \mathrm{span}\{[v, w] \mid v, w \in L\}$, the linear span of all Lie brackets. The $D^1(\cdot)$ notation must mean to take the derived Lie algebra.